# React, Material UI Menu error MUI: The `anchorEl` prop provided to the component is invalid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have created MUI Nav bar which has a couple of items on the right. Upon clicking on the user icon a dropdown menu should be displayed. The menu pops up but I get this error -

> > Warning: Failed prop type: MUI: The `anchorEl` prop provided to the component is invalid.
> > It should be an Element instance but it's `undefined` instead.
> > at Popover (https://inq73y.csb.app/node_modules/@mui/material/Popover/Popover.js:97:43)
> > at eval (https://inq73y.csb.app/node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-b63ca7c6.cjs.dev.js:43:23)
> > at Menu (https://inq73y.csb.app/node_modules/@mui/material/Menu/Menu.js:72:43)
> > at header
> > at eval (https://inq73y.csb.app/node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-b63ca7c6.cjs.dev.js:43:23)
> > at Paper (https://inq73y.csb.app/node_modules/@mui/material/Paper/Paper.js:62:43)
> > at eval (https://inq73y.csb.app/node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-b63ca7c6.cjs.dev.js:43:23)
> > at AppBar (https://inq73y.csb.app/node_modules/@mui/material/AppBar/AppBar.js:107:43)
> > at div
> > at eval (https://inq73y.csb.app/node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-b63ca7c6.cjs.dev.js:43:23)
> > at Box (https://inq73y.csb.app/node_modules/@mui/system/esm/createBox.js:27:40)
> > at ElevationScroll (https://inq73y.csb.app/src/App.js:32:28)
> > at App (https://inq73y.csb.app/src/App.js:43:33)

I have also tried using anchorEl in state and adding it to the menu as described in the MUI docs but in this approach, the menu pops up on the top left instead of right and there is a warning which seems like the same issue to me.

> > MUI: The `anchorEl` prop provided to the component is invalid.
> > The anchor element should be part of the document layout.
> > Make sure the element is present in the document or that it's not display none.
> > in Transition (created by Grow)
> > in Grow (created by FocusTrap)
> > in FocusTrap (created by ModalUnstyled)
> > in ModalUnstyled (created by Modal)
> > in Modal (created by MuiPopoverRoot)
> > in MuiPopoverRoot (created by Popover)
> > in Popover (created by MuiMenuRoot)
> > in MuiMenuRoot (created by Menu)
> > in Menu (created by App)
> > in App

I have searched a couple of links using refs and getting the nested components out of the parent but I was not able to get those.

This is the link to codesandbox - [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-frost-inq73y?file=/src/App.js)
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `anchorEl` property is expecting an element that is always available.  The code you have removes this element on close - this is the cause of the error.  The expected way to do it is to provide a `ref` (which is done via the `useRef` hook) to the element you want to be the anchor and control the visibility of the menu by its `open` property.

I made some changes to your code and got the error to go away.

```js
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
const anchorEl = React.useRef();

return (
  <>
    <ElevationScroll>
      <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
        <AppBar color="primary" position="fixed">
          <Toolbar>
          <Box display="flex" alignItems="center">
            <Typography>Menu Options </Typography>
          </Box>
          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }} />
          <Box sx={{ display: { xs: "none", md: "flex" } }}>
            <IconButton disableRipple>
              <SearchIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton disableRipple>
              <NotificationsActiveIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton 
              ref={anchorEl} 
              onClick={() => setOpen(true)} 
              disableRipple
            >
              <PersonOutlineOutlined />
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton disableRipple>
              <SettingsOutlined />
              </IconButton>
            </Box>
          </Toolbar>
          <Menu
            id="menu-appbar"
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            anchorOrigin={{
              vertical: "top",
              horizontal: "right"
            }}
            keepMounted
            transformOrigin={{
              vertical: "top",
              horizontal: "right"
            }}
            open={open}
            onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
          >
            <MenuItem>Profile</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>Logout</MenuItem>
          </Menu>
        </AppBar>
      </Box>
    </ElevationScroll>
  </>
  );
```

Comment: ok understood the case, but why it still shows the same warning right from the initial page loading?

Comment: I'm not seeing the warning in your example.  What is the warning you're getting on first render?

Comment: ` Failed prop type: Invalid prop `anchorEl` supplied to `ForwardRef(Menu)`, expected one of type [function].`

Answer (score 0):

ok, so if we provide the ref as below it works, the waring itself describes it

```js
anchorEl={()=> anchorEl.current}
```

But I'm not able to understand what difference it makes upon passing it as a function rather than

```js
anchorEl={anchorEl}
```